# ImmutableJS within react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, redux, immutable.js

Should our ImmutableJS data structures be connected and used within our react higher order components?

Should they even be used within react components in general? or should we convert to javascript structures before passing to react components?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

Comment: Looks like an interview question.